# Problem generating manifest. C# VS 2022 17.2.5

Tags: c#, manifest, visual-studio-2022

I have wpf project

- for Framework .NET Framework 4.7.2
- Build Any CPU

Previous Build was allways without problem.
After i opened the project from a new installation of visual studio 2022
I always get:

> Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly
> 'D:\Source\Repos..Toolbox.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
> was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I Just tried:

- Build Setting PlattForm Target differnet values
- Nuget Package Manager Package Manager Console update-Package -reinstall
- i added:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

I have some References but nothing special. To get sure i reinstalled
RestSharp.

Is there a way to find out which reference throws the error during creation of the Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Solution had nothing to do with Visual studio.

A virus scanner detected the new created .exe file and removed it.
The Error message from Manifest creation was missleading. The file was simply missing in the directory when generating the Manifest.